# Login site using cURL

Tags: curl

I am trying to login from cURL command line with the command
**curl --data "username=user&password=pass&submit=Login"  http://www.ip.com:8080/LoginApplication/Login.jsp**

And after that trying to access inner page using
**curl http://www.ip.com:8080/LoginApplication/Success.jsp**
But I am getting redirected to error page because of not logged in.

What I am missing in my first command so that it can maintain the session?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You most likely at least need to store the cookies you get back:

```
-c cookies.txt
```

... and then in your subsquent request(s) you want to read the cookies and possibly write them again if they get updated:

```
-b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt
```

... but the server can also reject you due to unrecognized User-agent, lack of Referer: and more...

Comment: I tried with -c cookies.txt and then i checked cookies.txt file contains FALSE. What could be the other reasons

Comment: having FALSE in the cookie file is normal and is not a sign of a failure

Comment: I have my server locally hosted, so is there any chance of unrecognized User-agent or lack of Referer (as I am novice in cUrl)